# Oil change, not enough oil coming out

Tags: oil, oil-change

So im changing my oil. last week i did it already but only 2 liters came out so i thought maybe i made a mistake like cold oil and not putting off the oil cap.

Now im changing the oil again (after i put in new 2 liters) with warm oil and the cap off. So far 2 liters came out and theres no steady oil stream anymore. Wtf could it be? Car fits 4.3 l oil

Comment: How long has passed since you added the last 2 litres?  How many miles have you done?

Comment: 0 miles. i didnt drive

Comment: Maybe you only had 2 liters in the engine in the first place.  You emptied 2L and added 2L,   Did you check the dip stick before emptying?

Comment: Yes i did. thats one if the reasons why i know its only 2 liters. Car is an  Mitsubishi Evo7

Comment: Are you saying that the dip stick was showing full before you dropped the oil out?

Comment: When you did the first change did you do the oil filter?

Comment: Yep i changed the oil filter. the 2nd time i didnt cuz its new ofc.

Comment: When you removed the old oil filter did any more oil come out (from the filter socket)?

Comment: I didnt check when i drained the first time but my oil catch thingy has a meter that shows u how much old oil is in there. So it said about 2.1 liters. I kind of couldnt believe that so i put in 2 liters new oil and tadaaa!  it looked like i overfilled. It was dark ao i think i was right. After 1 week checking again i had to put in about 300ml new oil to see oil on the dipstick. So i dont think i drove around with only 2 liters when i got the car Wouldnt the oil light tell me if theres only 2 liters oil in the car anyways? Sorry hard to explain for me im german

Comment: Yes oil came out where the filter was

Comment: Hmm.. a reasonable amount coming out when you remove the filter is what I'd expect - was thinking that if you hadn't done that it may explain the low drain amount.

Comment: i meant to say that it was dark Outside so i hope i was right reading the dipstick. anyways 1 week i checked the dipstick and oil was showing. not enough to be ok but nearly.

Comment: There's quite a significant difference between the notches on the dipstick - nearly a litre between min/max IIRC. If you had to add 0.3l to get it to just get oil to show on the dipstick then you'd *still* be about a litre shy of "full" - add in oil you (hopefully) prefilled into the filter and you're probably getting to the ballpark

Comment: *Wouldnt the oil light tell me if theres only 2 liters oil in the car anyways* not always. Most oil lights are based on oil pressure. There can easily be enough oil pressure to keep the light on even when the oil volume is significantly low to the point of being dangerous in terms of the oil's ability to perform.

Comment: ok i just filled in about 4 liters oil. seems like i misread the dipstick the last time in the dark. but wtf? i was driving around with 2 liters in my evo. Is it possible to burn 2 liter oil in 800km? I hope i didnt destroy anything i just got it fron japan 

Comment: I wouldn't expect a healthy Evo to go through ~2l in 800km. Running it that low isn't going to have been great for it, you *might* get away with it though but it's likely to have done some increased wear at the very least. I'd be watching the oil level like a hawk for the next few weeks.